# How to decrypt with password/salt an encrypted string with c++ openssl on nodejs

Tags: javascript, c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography

Im trying to decrypt an encrypted string with password/salt using `c++/openssl`.

In my attempt below the generated `key` on `js` matches the `key` generated from the `c++` function, but the `iv's` doesnt.

Its also throwing an error in the line `+= decipher.final('utf8');`:

`Uncaught Error Error: error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt`

**----EDIT----**

I got it working, edited version below, i wonder if its correctly or should be improved...

---

`nodejs` side:

```js
    function decrypt(encrypted, passphrase, salt) 
    {
       const keySize = 16;
       const ivSize = 16;
       const iterations = 1000;  // Same as in the C++ code
       const digest = 'sha1';   // Same as in the C++ code
       
       const keyAndIv = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(passphrase, salt, iterations, keySize + ivSize, digest);
       const key = keyAndIv.slice(0, keySize);
       const iv = keyAndIv.slice(keySize, keySize + ivSize);
       console.log('Key (hex):', key.toString('hex'));
       console.log('IV (hex):', iv.toString('hex'));
    
       const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
       let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
       decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    
       return decrypted;
    }
     
    const encryptedStr = 'YZ/vV9aj+ublWdLrOw44EQ=='
    const passphrase = 'password123';
    const salt = 'salt123'; 
    
    const decryptedStr = decrypt(encryptedStr, passphrase, salt);
    console.log(decryptedStr);
```

---

`c++/openssl` encryption function:

```cpp
    #include <openssl/rand.h>
    #include <openssl/evp.h>
    #include <openssl/bio.h>

     std::string stringToBase64(const std::string& input) 
     {
        BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    
        BIO* base64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
        BIO_set_flags(base64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);  // No line breaks
    
        BIO* bio_chain = BIO_push(base64, bio);    
        BIO_write(bio_chain, input.c_str(), input.length());
        BIO_flush(bio_chain);
    
        char* encoded_data;
        long encoded_length = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &encoded_data);
    
        std::string base64_string(encoded_data, static_cast<size_t>(encoded_length));
    
        // Free the BIOs
        BIO_free_all(bio_chain);
    
        return base64_string;
    }

   
    std::string encrypt(std::string str, const char* password, const char* salt)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    
    unsigned char derived[32]; // 32 bytes for both key and IV

    if(!PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(password), strlen(password), 
      reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(salt), strlen(salt), 
      1000, EVP_sha1(), 32, derived)) // Derive 32 bytes
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return std::string();
    }

    unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    // Use the first 16 bytes as the key
    memcpy(key, derived, 16);
    // Use the remaining 16 bytes as the IV
    memcpy(iv, derived + 16, 16);

    if (EVP_CipherInit(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), key, iv, true) != 1) 
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        return std::string();
    }
        
        const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = str.size();
        int len = 0;
        int outLen;
        
        int blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx);
        std::string cipherBuf;
        cipherBuf.resize(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + blocksize);
            
        if (EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(
            cipherBuf.data()), &outLen, reinterpret_cast<uchar *>
            (str.data()), str.size()) != 1)
        {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return std::string();
        }
        
        len += outLen;
      
        if (EVP_CipherFinal(ctx, reinterpret_cast<uchar *>
            (cipherBuf.data() + len), &outLen) != 1)
        {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            return std::string();     
        }
        
        len += outLen;
         
        cipherBuf.resize(len);
        // Cleanup
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    
        str = stringToBase64(cipherBuf); 
        // Clear cipherBuf. 
        memset(cipherBuf.data(), 0, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + blocksize);
    
        return str;
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
       const char* password = "password123";
       const char* salt = "salt123";
    
       std::string encrypted = encrypt("test123", password, salt);
    }
```

Comment: The documentation for EVP_BytesToKey is very clear that "Newer applications should use a more modern algorithm such as PBKDF2 as defined in PKCS#5v2.1 and provided by PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC. ". Change your C++ code to use PBKDF2 first.

Comment: @Botje ive changed it to PBKDF2 what will be the salt size in the js side?

Comment: ... the same as on the C++ side, I hope?

Comment: @Botje im asking how to declare it, `const ivSize = salt.length` i getting same error, but now the `key` generated on `js` match the key on `c++/openssl`

Comment: As far as I know the size of the IV is a parameter of the algorithm being used. PBKDF2 just deterministically generates a binary string of a certain size from a simple input and your JS code takes an arbitrary part of that as IV and key.